# jsp application in linux

Tags: java, linux, jsp

i have created a jsp application on netbeans which runs on Tomcat server.The home page of this application includes a login. The purpose of this application is that a logged in user can have a view of a file system usage of any linux system in the network by entering its ip address.The application uses "ssh username@ip" command to fetch the file system info.
everything is working well but the problem is that when my application is accessed from a user in the network via the tomcat server,and he tries to retrieve a file system of some ipadd, password to that system is asked on the server computer, it should be asked on the same system the application is accessed from?? can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

the ssh process is started on the server (where your application is running) ... you could use [java ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) the get the input and output stream of the ssh process, detect that the remote host is asking for credentials and let your application ask the user for them. your application should also be accessed through `https` to keep secure on all the way.